# Sort Gedmo Tree by arbitrary field using symfony4, doctrine2 and stofDoctrineExtensionsBundle

Tags: php, symfony, tree, symfony4, doctrine-extensions

### Introduction

For my personal project i am using:

- Windows 10 Pro
- XAMPP with PHP v7.2.14
- Postgres v10.6
- Symfony v4.2.4
- Doctrine v2.6.3
- [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) in order to manage Tree structure.

### Setting up

I did setup the tree structure (that represents directories and files) called `FileTree`. I added several custom fields to the tree: `item_name`, `item_extension`, `item_sort_value` and `is_file`.

### Problem

I can not get folders and files sorted by field `item_sort_value` in the fileTree!

At the same time i can sort items (as is needed) when only retrieving files inside custom filder.

### My CODE

> Retrieving (full size) folder file tree

```
public function getFileTreeNodeArray($file_tree_root_id): array
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $query = $em
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('ft')
        ->from(FileTree::class, 'ft')
        ->where('ft.root = :root_id')
        ->setParameter('root_id', $file_tree_root_id)
        ->orderBy('ft.root, ft.lft', 'ASC')
        //->addOrderBy('ft.itemSortValue', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery();

    $query->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_INCLUDE_META_COLUMNS, true);

    return $query->getArrayResult();
}
```

[image: file tree example]

> Retrieving files in the folder

```
public function getFileTreeNodeContentFilesByUploaderArray($file_tree_node_id, $user_id): array
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $is_file = true;
    $query = $em
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('ft')
        ->from(FileTree::class, 'ft')
        ->where('ft.parent = :file_tree_node_id')
        ->andWhere('ft.isFile = :is_file')
        ->andWhere('ft.uploader = :user_id')
        ->setParameter('file_tree_node_id', $file_tree_node_id)
        ->setParameter('is_file', $is_file)
        ->setParameter('user_id', $user_id)
        ->orderBy('ft.itemSortValue', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery();

    $query->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_INCLUDE_META_COLUMNS, true);

    return $query->getArrayResult();
}
```

[image: files in the folder]

### What i tried

I tried to use `reorder` and `reorderAll`, but "to no avail".

> An example

```
public function reorderFileTreeBranch($parent_id): void
{
    $repo_file_tree = $this->entityManager->getRepository(FileTree::class);

    $branch_node = $repo_file_tree->findOneBy(['id' => $parent_id]);
    $repo_file_tree->reorder($branch_node, 'item_sort_value', 'ASC');
    $this->entityManager->flush();
}
```

i can see many additional SQL queries (whenever i use `reorder` or `reorderAll`) in the `Symfony profiler`, so something is definitely going on, but after that - items are sorted the same in the tree...

### Conclusion

Am i doing something wrong?

Ideas and answers are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Well, after many tries and fails i managed to got it working as expected.
Turned out that `reorder` in `NestedTreeRepositoryTrait` did not return true on success... I fixed it - and so - now ordering woks as intended.